# No WEB-INF and META-INF folders while importing a Maven Project again in Netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I had a .war from a Maven Web App I build a while ago, and I wanted to import it again in Netbeans.
So I went and unzipped it, then from Netbeans I chose "Open Project" and navigated to the directory where the pom.xml file is, to import the whole project.

The project gets imported fine, with all its dependencies, but I actually only have those. No WEB-INF folder, nor META-INF folder, nor .jsp pages to speak of, and above all none of the java classes I wrote. Which is weird because the project path is correctly set where all those folders and files are.

This is the structure of my unzipped project:

[image: web app structure]

with the file pom.xml being inside META-INF/maven/it.unirc/myProjectName/

Here is what I get when I try to import the project:

[image: project in netbeans]

I also tried putting the pom.xml in the first directory, the one where all the WEB-INF and META-INF folders are, but nothing changes. The import only copies the dependencies and nothing else.

I don't understand, should I organize my folders differently for it to be imported correctly? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: A jar is not a maven project so you cannot import it to Netbeans. What you have imported is an extracted folder of the jar containing complied classes and resources. You need the source code from which the jar was created.

Comment: @leopal sorry I mispelled it. I meant a file .war

Comment: Again, a .war is also an archive just like jar with different structure. Why do you need to import a war? Don't you have access to the source code?

Comment: @leopal no, I haven't got the source code. I had to format my laptop and I was under the impression that exporting a .war was the best way to save my projects away. Have I done a rookie mistake here?

Comment: Yep, you should have pushed your code on a remote server ex github, bitbucket or archived it on a zip. This way, you would easily recreate the war. There may exist solution to achieve what you want, but I think it will not be easy.

Comment: @leopal I just found a workaround - after all, I only needed to check the code I had written in some of my classes: I used a java decompiler (jd-gui) to access the files. I'm still interested in knowing how to import a maven project correctly, without losing source code. But thank you for helping out!